# Struts pagination

Tags: struts2, struts

We are using struts, spring and hibernate in our project, I want to use pagination in struts, we can do the pagination using hibernate, Anyone knows how we can do it in struts?

Thank you

Cheers

Comment: As an answer said below, displaytag it's a nice library for pagination -> http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454267/struts2-bootstrap-datatable-how-to-paginate-without-load-all-data/36507871#36507871

Comment: Please use Data tables plugin for the Hibernate struts Pagination. (DataTables Plugin) https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 7):

You need to use an external jar, you cam use  [Struts Jquery Plugin](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)it's very good and easy;
An alterbative solution is [Displaytag](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/)
Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Well there is nothing much Struts2 can do here, all you need to pass certain values from your JSP page and use hibernate to fetch those records.
e.g

you can get total number of records which will get displayed and number of records you need to show on per page

Total Record=100/10 (number of record per page)=10
Which shows that you need to show data in 10 pages. secondly you need to pass start-index and offset to fetch that number of records from the DB.

to show records you can use Struts2 iterator tag.
i hope that will give you some idea and if you need any sort of example can be provided, but i believe its always good to try yourself.

Alternatively can use display tags which comes with pagination functionality.

Answer (score 2):

jquery with struts has a bug/problem or whatever. When u render 2nd page and then click on browser back, after again visiting the page displays wrong hover.

as Umesh Awasthi says u implement logic in action. This allows you to handle pagination in what u wanted to implement in most optimized way.

fetch only those records which are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use display-tag library in struts to display record in pagination view.It require only the list of pojos to be displayed.It will automatically display that pojos in pagination.You can set it property like page size etc

Answer (score 1):

In my earlier project I used struts with hibernate. We have implemented pagination but in a tricky way. We haven't used any third party library on front end or server end. What we did basically, In jsp pages we have hidden fields for target page number, no of records per page. On the clicking on pagination button/ page number we actually submitting the page and on hibernate level we are querying such that required records will be fetched using those hidden values. This same action used on all over the application for pagination.